# How to properly send env variables to image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I wrote a Docker image which need to read some variables so I wrote in the `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}
ENV USER=laravel

RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $UID -d /home/$USER $USER
RUN mkdir -p /home/$USER/.composer && \
    chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
```

This code actually allow me to create a `laravel` user which has the id of the user that starts the container.

So an user that pull this image actually set in the `docker-compose` section this content:

```
env_file: .env
```

which have:

```
GROUP_ID=1001
USER_ID=1001
```

For some weird reason that I don't understand, when I exec in the container with the pulled image, the user `laravel` is mapped with the id 1000 which that is the default value setted in the `Dockerfile`.

Instead, if I test the image using:

```
build:
  context: ./docker/php
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  args:
    - UID=${GROUP_ID:-1000}
    - GID=${USER_ID:-1000}
```

I can see correctly the user `laravel` mapped as `1001`. So the questions are the following:

1. is the UID variable not reading from env file?
2. is the default value overwriting the env value?

Thanks in advance for any help

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I tried to change the user id and group id in the bash script executed in the entrypoint, in the `Dockerfile` I have this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["start.sh"]
```

then, at the start of `start.sh` I've added:

```
usermod -u ${USER_ID} laravel
groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} laravel
```

the issue now is:

> usermod: user laravel is currently used by process 1
> groupmod: Permission denied.
> groupmod: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "when I exec in the container with the pulled image"? Does this mean you just start the container with ```exec``` or what? What docker image do you use there? Was the docker image build using the ```--build-arg``` and your vars?

Comment: I wrote a custom image and pushed to docker hub. So I tested the image locally using `--build-arg` and no issues, the id is set correctly, but when I pull the image from the hub and simply specify the env variables, I get the default value 1000 that I set in the Dockerfile

Comment: This is because you add a user in docker ```build phase``` and can not overwrite it with passing ```env``` in docker ```run``` phase! It works in you example with ```docker-compose``` file with ```build``` section as you re-create the docker image with different UID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker `build phase` and the `run phase` are the key moment here. New user is **added** in the `build phase` and hence it is important to **pass** dynamic values while building docker image in `build phase` with e.g.

```bash
docker build --build-arg UID=1001 --build-arg GID=1001 .
```

or the case which you have already used and where it works (i.e. docker image is re-created with expected IDs), in `docker-compose` file:

```
build:
  context: ./docker/php
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  args:
    - UID=${GROUP_ID:-1000}
    - GID=${USER_ID:-1000}
```

In `run phase`, i.e. starting the container instance of **already** built docker image, passing `env` does not overwrite vars of `build phase`. Hence, in you case you can omit passing envs when starting container.

Comment: So I suppose is not possible just set an env var?

Comment: In your case yes, you can not overwrite UID by setting env when starting container as the user added in build phase. But generally there are cases to overwrite vars in run phase, e.g. if vars used in CMD command of Dockerfile.

Comment: What about if I change the id and group id of the user in the entrypoint bash script of the image? could be a solution?

Comment: This could be a solution and you can overwrite it on run phase, while starting container. However i am not sure if this is a good and practical idea. Please consider voting and accepting the answer if it helped you with your original question, i.e. to understand why the uid was not overwritten.

Comment: With what user you are starting the container and changing user-id and group-id of ```laravel```? You have to probably start with e.g. root, change ```laravel``` user, switch user to ```laravel``` and start your process. If it does not help, this is another question and diverges from topic of original question and I would suggest to open a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249165/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-m19v).